# Getting ICS to work as a development phone lg o2x

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I have manually flashed a kang build(SELFKANG3) of ICS android 4.0.3 to my lg optimus 2x, but i cant get it to work as a development phone. On gingerbread, i just plugged it in and debugged my applications on it, but now it doesn't show up on my computer. All that happens is that it pops up an autorun window called LG-P990 with a couple of options. I have checked USB-debugging but without any luck. Please help me and thanks SO much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It's possible it's a problem with the rom, or the USB drivers for the Optimus 2X don't support Ice Cream Sandwich. Try plugging it into a Mac or a Linux machine, neither of which require USB drivers for phones, and see if ADB will recognize the device there.

Comment: i could try that, but then i'll have to begin with virtual machines and all of that, and setup android sdk and eclipse there plus that i'll have to copy my workspace over to it and start the virtual machine each time i program

Comment: Or find a friend or acquaintance with Mac or Linux! They're not that unpopular of operating systems. If you're unable to get the phone working over USB you would probably be fine developing your app's ICS functionality in an emulator. That's what I've done up to this point

Comment: Not saying that they are bad, i've been using them before and i like them very much. But since none i know have linux. But some have mac. But i can't borrow their machine each time i'll develop

Comment: Oh, I understand that, I was just suggesting you test it once on a friend's machine to help pinpoint where the issue was coming from